# Clustered infrastructure on VPS

Tags: vpn, cluster, vps

I want to build infrastructure which is clustered. Only option I have is VPSs in container. The following is how should infrastructure should look like.[image: Infractructure]

All incoming traffic comes to Fw1. Proxy redirects request to AppServerX. Databases are situated in another subnetwork. Access to the Secure zone is over Fw2. Monitor machine monitors all other machines health and firewalls also. As you can see Application servers and Database servers are clustered  for HA. Also firewalls should be clustered for HA.
Connections between machines should be over VPN. Theoretically all sounds good, but practically I have problems. As VPN I'm planning to use OpenVPN server/client architecture and site-to-site between zones.
But I have some problem, as I cannot understand how to make clustered firewall. And monitor all machines, also the firewalls which are in slave mode. Maybe the architecture is wrong. Thats why any suggestion is appreciated. Please, also write about best practices.

Thanks.

Comment: you want clustered firewall, or failover ? i mean you want to load balance the traffic, or just when one of them go down, the other one take his place as master?

Comment: failover firewall. but also want that the monitor machine to be failovered and in one vpn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, to achieve HA among firewall cluster there are two ways, first that you are using which is to have an **external Monitor** that will keep checking the health of all servers and Firewalls via heartbeat. In case of failover the other firewall from the cluster will be given the responsibility to route and manage connections. The other way is to let the **cluster itself identify failover** and then one of the slave firewall from cluster will become master. All connections states will be gracefully taken care by the new master.

Second thing that you should decide that whether you want active-backup or active-active configuration for your clusters accordingly complexity will differ.
In active-backup only one of your firewall will be active (Master) and others will be shadowed (slave). Whereas in case of active-active master as well as slaves will be in working mode.

Now once you decide how you want to achieve HA for your firewall cluster, you need either **Heartbeat or Keepalived** for maintaining the HA cluster, it will keep monitoring the firewalls for failover and keeping track of master and slave nodes, whenever failover occurs on master node a new master is chosen by communicating within the cluster. To replicate the firewall or syncing connection states among the cluster **Conntrackd** can be used. It will always keep the cluster nodes ready to take over the responsibility of master gracefully without being noticed by the network.

The concept of **Virtual IPs** is used to switch to one of the slave nodes in failover scenarios.

So, am assuming your current design works well without HA cluster hence you can continue with your current architecture and embed HA using these software in your cluster.

The important thing is you should be clear about what all you want to achieve from you HA cluster and accordingly move ahead with implementation. I hope this would help.